# Connect to openstack is failing

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-shade

I have written a bit of python code to interact with an Openstack instance; using the [shade](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214836997-How-to-launch-and-delete-OpenStack-instances-using-Python-and-Shade) library.

The call

```
myinstance = shade.openstack_cloud(cloud='mycloud', **auth_data)
```

works fine on my local Ubuntu installation; but fails on our "backend" servers (running RHEL 7.2).

> File "mystuff/core.py", line 248, in _create_connection
>       myinstance = shade.openstack_cloud(cloud='mycloud', **auth_data)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shade-1.20.0-py3.5.egg/shade/**init**.py", line 106, in openstack_cloud
>       return OpenStackCloud(cloud_config=cloud_config, strict=strict)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shade-1.20.0-py3.5.egg/shade/openstackcloud.py", line 312, in **init**
>       self._local_ipv6 = _utils.localhost_supports_ipv6()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shade-1.20.0-py3.5.egg/shade/_utils.py", line 254, in localhost_supports_ipv6
>       return netifaces.AF_INET6 in netifaces.gateways()['default']
>
> AttributeError: module 'netifaces' has no attribute 'AF_INET6'

The admin for that system tells me that IPv6 is not enabled there; maybe that explains the fail. I did some research, but couldn't find anything to prevent the failure.

*Any* thoughts are welcome.

Update: I edited my clouds.yml; and it looks like this:

```
# openstack/shade config file 
# required to connect provisioning using the shade module
client:
    force_ipv4: true
clouds:
    mycloud:
        auth:
        user_domain_name: xxx
        auth_url: 'someurl'
    region_name: RegionOne
```

I also tried `export OS_FORCE_IPV4=True` - but the error message is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go through the OpenStack [os-client-config documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/os-client-config/#ipv6), there they have mentioned about `IPV6` related issue.

> IPv6 is the future, and you should always use it if your cloud
>   supports it and if your local network supports it. Both of those are
>   easily detectable and all friendly software should do the right thing.
>   However, sometimes you might exist in a location where you have an
>   IPv6 stack, but something evil has caused it to not actually function.
>   In that case, there is a config option you can set to unbreak you
>   force_ipv4, or OS_FORCE_IPV4 boolean environment variable.

So, using these `boolean` config you can force appropriate network protocol. Adding below lines to your `clouds.yaml` file

```
 client:
   force_ipv4: true
```

will force `IPV4` and hope it will resolve your issue.

Edit by OP: unfortunately the above doesn't help; fixed it by reworking `shade-1.20.0-py3.5.egg/shade/_utils.py`: I changed the return statement

```
return netifaces.AF_INET6 in netifaces.gateways()['default']`
```

to a simple

```
return False
```

And stuff is working. Of course, this is just a workaround; but a bug report was filed as well.

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue and so just added a probable solution.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat 